# Ascending triangle wave formula

Tags: statistics, triangles, wave-equation

I'm trying to find a formula which can plot points that move down one unit 60% of the time, and up two units 40% of the time, similar to how the stock markets move, in an up trend.

I started with the triangle wave formula, but I don't know exactly how to incorporate percentage chance, or compounding effects.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the function you’re describing will not look like an ascending triangle in the language of technical analysis, but rather like an ascending channel or bear flag (depending on timeframe).

Answer (score 1):

What you’re describing to me sounds like a 1D random walk with right step 2, left step -1, and right step probability 0.4. To define this formally, let ${X_1,X_2,...}$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables with common distribution given by
$$P(X_1=2)=0.4$$
$$P(X_1=-1)=0.6.$$
Then your random function $F$ will be defined on the integers by
$$F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$$

To fill in the gaps, following your triangle wave model, we would interpolate linearly by setting $$F(n+a)= (1-a)F(n)+aF(n+1)$$ for $n\ge 0$ any integer and $0<a<1$. But to really fill in the gaps properly, you would want to instead use [Brownian motion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion), which is a reasonable model for how the stock market actually behaves.